# Billing question when using Firebase Cloud Functions as an API

Tags: firebase

I'm looking at using Firebase Cloud Functions with express server to serve data from my firestore. The issue I can't seem to find an answer to is regarding the requests my cloud functions will make to my firestore data. I understand how the firestore billing works, billed per record read/write/delete. However, when cloud functions are making the requests does it count as a new read/write/delete to each firestore record every time another user requests some data, or does it cache data in some way? Or, could I have firebase cloud functions hold the firestore data in memory in a way where it reads all records once, listening for changes like firebase does client-side, and serving results from the data thats in memory whenever my API request comes in? Or is it the case that Firebase Cloud Functions already holds an open connection in memory to the data in my firestore?

Answer (score 0):

> does it count as a new read/write/delete to each firestore record every time another user requests some data

Yes it does count like a normal read/write/delete operation with the Firebase SDK.

> could I have firebase cloud functions hold the firestore data in memory

Technically maybe you can, but you get billed for Ghz-seconds on CPU and Gb-second memory on Cloud Functions, so overall bad idea.